# Set User Agent for RemoteMediaClient and MediaMetaData of Google Cast(TM)

Tags: android, google-cast

I integrated support for Google Cast (TM) to my app. My app has own user agent. I block other user agents on the server side. I found that when media is played on Android TV via Google Cast (TM) client uses user agent as a browser. Is it possible to set user agent for RemoteMediaClient and MediaMetaData?

```
private void loadRemoteMedia(boolean autoPlay) {
    if (mCastSession == null) {
        return;
    }

    RemoteMediaClient remoteMediaClient = mCastSession.getRemoteMediaClient();
    if (remoteMediaClient == null) {
        return;
    }

    remoteMediaClient.load(buildMediaInfo(), autoPlay);
}

private MediaInfo buildMediaInfo() {
    MediaMetadata mediaMetadata = new MediaMetadata(MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_TV_SHOW);

    mediaMetadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_TITLE, "title");

    return new MediaInfo.Builder(selectedStreamingURL)
        .setContentType("application/x-mpegurl")
        .setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_LIVE)
        .setMetadata(mediaMetadata)
        .build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For all Cast devices, the Chrome browser is the user agent and controls the HTTP request headers. For DRM content and if you use the CAF receiver, there are various options for you to control access to your content:
https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/caf_receiver_features#drm